# Dynamic image Javascript code

Tags: javascript

Can you recommend some javascript that will create a frontpage image rotation with links similar to this:

http://www.jhilburn.com/

Preferably javascript only in the body would be good.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with jQuerys fading functions!